# No such column error

Tags: android, eclipse

I still have this error in android !
I read many solutions but they weren't helpful ..
The error is : no such column : Star: , while compiling : select count(*) AS Total from tblf where recId>1 and name=Star

What is the wrong? and how can i fix it ?

```
private void useRawQuery3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] args = {"1","Star"} ;
    String mySQL = " select count(*) AS Total from tblf" 
    + " where recId>" + args[0] + " and name=" + args[1] ;
    Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(mySQL, null) ;
    int index = c1.getColumnIndex("Total") ;
    c1.moveToFirst() ;
    int theTotal = c1.getInt(index) ;
    Toast.makeText(this, " Total3="+theTotal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
}
```

Comment: Clear your data of application from your phone. then restart your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select count(*) AS Total from tblf where recId>1 and name='Star'
```

Meaning:

```
String mySQL = " select count(*) AS Total from tblf" 
    + " where recId>" + args[0] + " and name='" + args[1] + "'" ;
```

Comment: but i should use that way .. 
where is the wrong in my way ?

Comment: Yours has no single quote before and after Star

Comment: thaanks .. it works ..
what are the rules to write like these sentences ? 
mean like spaces ,quotations and so on ??

Answer (score 0):

Your Change on Database will be applied when you clear data from your device or simulator. So:

1. Clear your data of application from your device.
2. Restart your application.